# How do I get projectId from GoogleCredentials?

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataproc

Using Python I would like to get a list of all my Dataproc clusters on Google Cloud.

I have service account credentials stored in a JSON keyfile whose location is referred to by env var GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import os
import googleapiclient.discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials


def build_dataproc_service(credentials):
    return googleapiclient.discovery.build("dataproc", "v1", credentials=credentials)


def list_clusters():
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    dataproc = build_dataproc_service(credentials)
    clusters = dataproc.projects().regions().clusters().list(projectId="my-project", region="REGION").execute()
    return clusters


if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_clusters()
```

As you can see I have hardcoded the projectId (`"my-project"`). Given that the projectId exists in the JSON keyfile I had hoped I could obtain it simply be interrogating a property of the `credentials` object, but no such property exists. The projectId *does* exist embedded within the `credentials._service_account_email` string property but extracting it from there is clunky and feels wrong.

I assume there must be a better way. How can I obtain the projectId of the project in which the service account resides?

Note that initially I intend for this code to be run in a docker container on a Google Compute Engine instance however one day in the future I may want to run on GKE. Not sure if that affects the answer or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A formal way to think about this is that while projectId is sometimes a property of a *service account*, a projectId is not generally a property of a long-lived *credential*. For example, think of your offline-installed personal credential you use with the `gcloud` CLI, if any, associated with your Google account/email address. That email identity doesn't reside in *any* cloud project, and yet can be used to derive a GoogleCredential object.

Technically, if you want to do it "properly" you'd need a master service account that has permissions to `GET` service account descriptions in all the projects that hold the actual service accounts you plan to use, and then call IAM API's [projects.serviceAccounts.get](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/get) on the service-account email address, not on the "credential" objet. The responses there can identify the project id in which the service account resides. This is equivalent to the `gcloud` command:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts describe my-service-account@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

However, as Dagang says, it's often going to backfire in the long run to start baking in assumptions that the service account will only be used for operations on the projects in which it resides. In particular, while `service account` resources  themselves live inside projects, they are often used in a cross-project manner. One common operational pattern is to use a single GCP project to manage a large number of service accounts that are then granted various fine-grained access to resources in other GCP projects.

Comment: So it sounds as though my best bet is to get the projectId from the compute engine metadata server. That makes an assumption that my code is running in the same project in which the Dataproc  clusters reside, in my case that is a safe assumption.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think client code is supposed to extract project ID from GoogleCredentials. See this code snippet from the [API doc](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.client.html).

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

PROJECT = 'bamboo-machine-422'
ZONE = 'us-central1-a'
request = service.instances().list(project=PROJECT, zone=ZONE)
response = request.execute()

print(response)
```

You might be able to infer project ID from `credentials._service_account_email`, but that is not reliable. Also, a service account in project A is not bound to the project, it might also have permissions on other projects.

Answer (score 2):

The service account credentials .json contains the project_id, so you can do:

```
# If this is running in a cloud function, then GCP_PROJECT should be defined
if 'GCP_PROJECT' in os.environ:
    project_id = os.environ['GCP_PROJECT']

# else if this is running locally then GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS should be defined
elif 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' in os.environ:
    with open(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'], 'r') as fp:
        credentials = json.load(fp)
    project_id = credentials['project_id']
else:
    raise Exception('Failed to determine project_id')
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the ProjectId from the UnderlyingCredential

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(googleCredentialPath);
var projectId = ((Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential)credential.UnderlyingCredential).ProjectId;
```

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 2):

In C#

```
var credentials = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault();
var projectId = (credentials.UnderlyingCredential as dynamic).ProjectId as string;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you cast to dynamic, rather than ServiceAccountCredential?

Comment: @StuartQ - he did it because ServiceAccountCredential doesn't contain ProjectId property. That's also the only answer that worked for me in .NET.